# Homogenization of the image of $t \mapsto (t,t^3,t^4)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given the map $f: \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^3_{\mathbb{C}}$ defined by $t \mapsto (t,t^3,t^4)$ prove that the image of $f$ is an affine variety and that the union of $Im(f)$ with the point $(0:0:0:1)$ gives a projective variety in $\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}$.

Now, I found the equations of $V=Im(f)$ to be $x_1x_2-x_3=0$ and $x_1^3-x_2=0$, but homogenising this I get $x_1x_2-x_3x_0=0 $ and $ x_1^3-x_0^2x_2=0$. Call the projective variety defined by the last two equations $\overline{V}$ and let $U_0=\{(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3) \in \mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}|  x_0\not = 0\}$, we now have $\overline{V} \cap (\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}\setminus U_0) \not = \{(0:0:0:1)\}$. For example $(0:0:1:0) \in (\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}\setminus U_0)$ also satisfies the equations, which would mean that we have to add more than $(0:0:0:1)$ to $V$, right?
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here another way to prove the statement without homogenization of ideals. The map $(t:u)\mapsto (tu^3:t^3u:t^4:u^4)$ from $\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^1$ to $\mathbb{P}^3_\mathbb{C}$ is a morphism such that when we restrict to $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^1$ we get your original map $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{C}^3$. The image of $(0:1)$ is $(0:0:0:1)$. Since $\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^1$ is proyective its image is closed in $\mathbb{P}^3_\mathbb{C}$ and therefore a proyective variety.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the variety given by homogenizing the generators of an ideal may be larger than the closure of the variety in projective space.  You must homogenize all the elements of $I$.  You can, however, homogenize using a graded Groebner basis.

Using the grevlex order, I used Magma to compute a Groebner basis (using grevlex order) as
$$x_2^3-x_1x_3^2\qquad x_1^2x_3-x_2^2\qquad x_1x_2-x_3\qquad x_1^3-x_2.$$

When you homogenize these, you get 
$$x_2^3-x_1x_3^2\qquad x_1^2x_3-x_0x_2^2\qquad x_1x_2-x_0x_3\qquad x_1^3-x_0^2x_2.$$
Notice that $(0:0:1:0)$ does not satisfy the first element of the Groebner basis.

Additionally, at $x_0=0$, by the fourth polynomial, it follows that $x_1=0$.  Then, substituting this into the first polynomial, you have that $x_2=0$.  Therefore, the points in the closure are of the form $(0:0:0:x_3)$.  By dividing by the nonzero $x_3$ (since this is a point in $\mathbb{P}_C^3$), you get the only extra point, $(0:0:0:1)$.

Comment: Thanks for this method. However, we didn't deal with Groebner bases in the course so I'll have to get back to this when I know more.